# Use LD_PRELOAD on ubuntu to intercept the network interaction of mysqld

Tags: mysql, c, networking, ld-preload

I want to use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept the network interaction(including listen, bind, send, recv,read,write, recvmsg, sendmsg of libc.so.6) of `mysqld`.

I can intercept the network interaction of my own programs, but it didn't work on `mysqld`.

Could anyone please tell me the reason? Or `mysqld` uses other network functions instead of *send/recv*, *read/write*, *recvmsg/sendmsg* the to perform network interactions?

Comment: Thank you. I have viewed that question before. But it didn't solve my problems. Because I think mysqld dynamically loads the libc.so.6 and I have confirmed that by using ld /usr/sbin/mysqld.

Comment: Right, sorry, Can you post output of `ls -l $(which mysqld)`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16097088 Sep 20 04:47 /usr/sbin/mysqld`, I also have confirmed that `/etc/init.d/mysql` and `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` also use `/usr/sbin/mysqld`